# Android android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: android

I am linking my android app with facebook and call an Async task to authenticate fb user and then in handler calling another Async task to link the fb account in my database. On recieving info from second Async task I am showing process dialog with context 'this'. There are process dialog in both Async tasks also. Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it show

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@422608e8 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Answer (score 2):

This exception occurred while app was trying to notify user from the background thread by opening a Dialog.

However, according to Google Play console, exception occurred very often and seemed very consistent.

You should use the applicationContext instead of passing the activity.
`Context appContext = this.getApplicationContext();`
must go, and instead you use a pointer to the `activity` you're in.

So wherever you have passed the pointer of `activity` or `this` instead try to pass the `context`.